# PHP MySql Record Count with Date Selection, LIMIT and Paging

Tags: mysql, date, pagination

I have got myself into a bit of a mess trying figure out the best way of counting the total number of records (for a paging selector) before applying a LIMIT in the sql clause.

I've been using 2 queries to achieve this, varying the WHERE clause for the particular view I want.

```
$sqlcount = "SELECT COUNT(invnum) AS num 
FROM tblinvoices
WHERE invcustid>0 AND invstat>0 AND invdate 
BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'

$sqlquery = "SELECT $fieldlist 
FROM tblinvoices 
INNER JOIN tblcontacts 
ON tblinvoices.invcustid = tblcontacts.ID 
WHERE invcustid>0 AND invstat>0 AND invdate 
BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
ORDER BY invdate
LIMIT 0,$pagerows";
```

My problem is that every example I see for DATE and COUNT queries together with PAGING vary in method greatly, and I'd love to know the best way combining these requirements in a flexible and efficient way.

I originally chose the BETWEEN method for flexibility, but many examples (for date ranges) use clauses such as -

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS date1, MAX(date) AS date2 FROM mytable
WHERE (MONTH(date) = (SELECT Month(MAX(date))-1 FROM mytable )
OR MONTH(date) = (SELECT Month(MAX(date))-2 FROM mytable ))
AND YEAR(date) = (SELECT YEAR(MAX(date))
FROM mytable)
```

I've not been able to combine that sort of statement with COUNT and LIMIT for paging purposes, and don't know if its possible to do both in one operation (I have 'presumed' its not possible because the LIMIT will affect COUNT)

Any advice or example of the best way of meeting (what I thought would be) this common requirement will be most gratefully received. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you're asking - are you using both these queries together all the time to get a count, and then the records to match that count?  If so, perhaps a single SQL statement using GROUP BY and COUNT would do the trick then.

My rule of thumb is KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid), so I personally like to stick with the BETWEEN method where possible, though there are always circumstances that dictate otherwise.  I'm not sure though that you can separate DATE and COUNT in any way though.  You're using it select *which* records will be in the recordset, and COUNT is an aggregate function that acts on groups of those selected records (used with GROUP BY).

Comment: Ok Greg, thanks for confirming that BETWEEN is Ok. Sorry for usage confusion, I just used 2 separate SQL varnames to indicate they were 2 independent queries. I have just presumed that you need to do a COUNT(id) using identical WHERE query first, which should be fairly fast, because you can omit the JOIN in my example, and then do the SELECT for the full recordset, with JOIN, DATE range selection and LIMIT clause. My question was wide because there seems to be many ways of doing it, but the end result always looks clunky after ADO. Is my example probably the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: Well, on the premise that you're writing well formed SQL on normalized tables, the database engine is designed to handle data management tasks "efficiently", so I'd say that those queries will work just fine if they're accomplishing what you want.  Purists might argue with that statement, and may well be academically right, but unless you're having performance problems, I don't see anything wrong with the SQL in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: I do rigidly normalize tables from habit. You have reassured me (I'm amateur) that I haven't strayed too far off track. Thanks bro.